# How to fix hero video extending beyond 100vh and not playing only on chrome despite working on safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a hero video instead of a hero image with some dynamic text on the top. The problem is that the video will extend beyond the 100vh on chrome only and it won't play. I want the function to be similar to this: https://kriesi.at/themes/enfold-startup/#av_section_2, this is what I have: https://finag.sgedu.site/ It works perfectly on safari and firefox but not on chrome. This is a screenshot of how my issue looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbjg9.jpg

I have concluded the issue is with how chrome re-sizes the window. If I reduce the window it will eventually align to the 100vh and continue working as it is supposed to do. screenshot of page working as intended on chore with a breakpoint of 1024 https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2rOC.jpg
Screenshot of a page not working on chrome with a breakpoint of 1440

My HTML:

```
<div id="fullScreenDiv">
        <video autoplay loop id="video">
            <source src="hero.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    <div id="messageBox">
        <div class="hero container">
            <h1>We Deliver</h1>
            <h1 class="quotes">Authentic Experiences</h1>
            <h1 class="quotes">Video and Audio Support</h1>
            <h1 class="quotes">Meeting support and Set Up</h1>
            <h1 class="quotes">Technology Maintenance </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Test 1</h1>
    <h1>Test 2</h1>
    <h1>Test 3</h1>
    <h1>Test 4</h1>
    <h1>Test 5</h1>
    <h1>Test 6</h1>
    <h1>Test 7</h1>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#fullScreenDiv {

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
}

#video {

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#messageBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 114, 206, 0.5);
    color: white;
}



.container {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 16px;
    position: relative;
}


.quotes {
    display: none;
}

.hero {
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 16px;
    position: relative;
}

My JS (it does not directly affect the video but is for the dyanmic text placed in the center of the video)

$(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();
            })();
```

I expect the outcome to be the same as it is on safari or firefox, however, chrome is behaving completely different by not playing the video and by having the video overflow its parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is: you can try adding css property [`overflow: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to the `#fullScreenDiv` element so the child video does not extend beyond the parent

Comment: Hey, thank you for the tip!!!! That actually fixed the main issue. The video is still not playing on Chrome but I think I might be able to figure that out now. Thank you again!

Comment: You need to put `muted` html property on the video so Chrome plays it properly. Please consider accepting as answer if my answer helped, thanks.

Comment: Hello! Thank you! I am kinda new to using this platform and I tried to "upvote" it and the system simply didn't let me because of how new my account is. Sorry for taking long to figure it out, I assume I have to click on the check mark.